# how to better process the huge history data in the kafka topic by using spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am experiencing an issue to start spark streaming on a really big kafka topic, there are around 150 million data in this topic already and the topic is growing super fast.

When I tried to start spark streaming and read data from the beginning of this topic by setting kafka parameter ("auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest"), it always try to finish all 150 million data processing in the first batch and return a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error. There isn't a lot calculation in this spark stream app though.

Can I have a way to process the history data in this topic in first several batches but not all in first batch?

Bunch of thanks in advance!
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control spark kafka-input reading rate with following spark configuration `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` .

You can configure this by giving how many docs you want to process per batch.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition","<docs-count>")
```

Above config process `<docs-count>*<batch_interval>` records per batch.

You can find more info about above config [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).